# Cannot switch to TTYs or back

Tags: linux-mint, console, tty

I just upgraded to Mint 13 - KDE x64

I am unable to switch to ttys by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> .. <kbd>F6</kbd> keys. The gettys are running and I can switch to the terminals with the `sudo chvt 1` command.

I have browsed to quite a few topics and have not reached a solution that works. I even reinstalled grub with `terminal=console`. Once I make a selection at the boot menu, I do not see any boot messages - just KDE starting after a few seconds.

How do I fix this?

Comment: That is determined by your X server config (/etc/X11/xorg.conf). There is an option `Option     "DontVTSwitch"`. Do you have that enabled?

Comment: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` does not seem to exist. Is there any other file where I could look for this option? I tried looking at other files in the directory and could not find it.

Comment: What does `locate xorg.conf` show you?

Comment: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-quirks.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-trackpoint.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.d.5.gz

When I attempted to create a xorg.conf, X11 did not start!

Comment: @Lord Loh. - How did you create the xorg.conf? You can try `sudo Xorg -configure` to create an initial file that should work. If it does, you can add the `Option` described above.

Comment: Someone else with this problem discovered that their [keys had been remapped](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cant-switch-to-virtual-console-from-gnome-133112/). A possibility for you?

Comment: `sudo Xorg -configure` failed with an error that the number of screens created does not match the number of devices. I am now inclined to think that this is a hotkey mapping. However, the KDE keyboard shortcut editor does not show me any options to add one for switching terminals :-(

Comment: Thanks to inspiration from the comments here, I managed to fix it. (http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/virtual-terminal-not-working/) was a great help. I entered the `kcmshell4 kcm_keyboard` > advanced tab > Miscellaneus compatibility option > and unchecked the special keys (ctrl + alt + <key>) handled in a server. Things went in place! I would still like to know where this sets the options in configuration files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to inspiration from the comments here, I managed to fix it. 
[This](http://mattcutts.com/blog/virtual-terminal-not-working) was a great help. I entered the `kcmshell4 kcm_keyboard` > advanced tab > Miscellaneus compatibility option > and unchecked the special keys (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd>) handled in a server. Things went in place! I would still like to know where this sets the options in configuration files...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem in Gnome Desktop 2.28.2 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation 6.9.  My initial steps differed from [@LordLoh.'s steps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50055/212837), but the final steps were identical:

1. Navigated the Red Hat menu: System → Preferences → Keyboard
2. Visited the "Layouts" tab.
3. Clicked the "Layout Options..." button.
4. Expanded the "Miscellaneous compatibility options" section.
5. Deselected/unchecked the "Special keys (Ctrl+Alt+<key>) handled in a server" option.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was as follows:

1. Run `kcmshell5 kcm_keyboard`
2. Go to 'Advanced' tab
3. Expand 'Alt/Win key behavior'
4. Select 'Alt and Meta are on Alt'
5. Apply settings